# Apply scroll in tbody and making header fix

Tags: html, css

I have div-->table-->thead-->tbody , if I apply height and overflow to parent , it shows scroll bar in whole table, what if i want to show scroll bar only in tbody?

Comment: apply height for `tbody` and apply `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
.scrollClass {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display:block;
    border:2px solid blue;
    width:100%;
}         

.tbodyclass {
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Right side scroll is coming but tbody content is mess still.. Everything getting aligned left. I have only applied scrollclass to tbody..

Comment: width:100% not making any change.